# How to import .class files after specifying the Build path

Tags: java

Hi in eclipse i have a project folder called SimpleDrop. I have already specified the build path by adding the external class folder goo which contains the .class files i want to use in SimpleDrop. But I still get error in my programs when trying to import a class from goo.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the build path has the folder with all of the required classes,
 `import ClassName;`
If there are sub-folders that contain the needed class files,
 `import package.name.here.ClassName;`
Eclipse also has a shortcut key to fix imports: Ctrl + Shift + O (O as in Oscar)